# How to explain the execution path of this Cypher query?

Tags: graph, neo4j, insert, cypher

Imagine the following graph:

[image]

And this query:

```
MATCH(p:Person {id:1})
MATCH (p)-[:KNOWS]-(s)
CREATE (p)-[:LIVE_IN]->(:Place {name: 'Some Place'})
```

Now, why five `LIVE_IN`, `Place` are created even though `s` is not involved in the `CREATE` statement? is there any place in the docs that explain this behavior?

**Note:**  this is not about `MERGE` vs `CREATE`, although `MERGE` can solve it.

**EDIT:** In response to @Tomaz answer: I have deliberately placed `MATCH (p)-[:KNOWS]-(s)` in the query and I know how it will behave. I am asking for found explanations. For example, is `CREATE` will execute for each path or row in the matched patterns regardless of the node involved in the `CREATE`? what if you have complex matched patterns such as, disconnected graph, Trees...etc?

Also note that the direction of relationship `KNOWS` (`-` vs `->`) will effect the number of returned rows (9 vs 1), but `CREATE` will execute five times regardless of the direction.

**Update:**

I have added 3 other node `Office` and issued the following query:

```
MATCH(p:Person {id:1})
MATCH (p)-[:KNOWS]-(s)
MATCH (o:Office)
CREATE (p)-[:LOVE]->(:Place {name: 'Any Place'})
```

And as result: 15 `LOVE` `Place` have been created, so it seems to me that cypher performs *Cartesian Product* between all nodes:

`p` refer to 1 nodes, `s` refer to 5 nodes, `o` refer to 3 nodes => 1 * 5 * 3 = 15

But I can not confirm this form neo4j docs unfortunately.

Comment: Is there a reason why the query needs to get `s`?

Comment: @cybersam In this case no, but in my real app yes there are very similar scenarios

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Person with id 1 has five neighbors.

In your query you start with:

```
MATCH(p:Person {id:1})
```

This produces a single row, where it finds the node you are looking for.
The next step is:

```
MATCH (p)-[:KNOWS]-(s)
```

This statement found 5 neighbors, so your cardinality or number of rows increases to five. And then you run a create statement for each row, which in turn creates five Places. You could for example lower the cardinality back to 1 before doing the `CREATE` and you'll create only a single place:

```
MATCH(p:Person {id:1})
MATCH (p)-[:KNOWS]-(s)
// aggregation reduces cardinality to 1
WITH p, collect(s) as neighbors
CREATE (p)-[:LIVE_IN]->(:Place {name: 'Some Place'})
```

When doing cypher query, always have in mind the cardinality you are operating.

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer my question, I deliberately placed `MATCH (p)-[:KNOWS]-(s)` and I know how it will behave. I am asking for found explanation? I mean is `CREATE` will execute for each path in the matched patterns, what if the matched patterns forms a disconnected graph?

Comment: Can you give example